# How to compose variable name dynamically?

Tags: groovy

I need to generate a list,and name it's items based on for-loop index
number, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<someNumber;i++){
    Model m_{$i}=Mock()   //but this doesn't work
    ......
    models.add(i,m_{$i})
}
```

then they can be distinguished by name when debugging test code(shame to tell this) within eclipse,but it doesn't work, so how to make it work?

update:add image to tell why I want to append for-loop index to variable name
[image]

Comment: Why would you like to do it like that? Maybe Map would be better in this case?

Comment: Also, can't you just get the one you're after by querying eg: `models[1]` rather than `m_1`?

Comment: For debugging test code(shame to tell this),but please tell me this is possible or not?

Comment: During test code execution,some item will be added or removed,so I need to know which is added or removed?

Comment: How they are going to be removed? From `models` list?

Comment: yes,so I need to check which one has been removed.

Comment: Alex, maybe you could explain your problem to the groovy-eclipse maillist: http://xircles.codehaus.org/lists/eclipse-plugin-user@groovy.codehaus.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add some property to your Mock class at runtime thanks to Groovy's [MetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Per-Instance+MetaClass). Take a look at this sample snippet:

```
class myClass {
    String someProperty
}

def models = []
10.times { it ->
    def instance = new myClass(someProperty: "something")
    instance.metaClass.testId = it
    models.add(instance)
}

// delete some
println "Removing object with testId = " + models.remove(4).testId
println "Removing object with testId = " + models.remove(7).testId

def identifiersOfObjectsAfterRemoves = models.collect { it.testId }

def removedObjectsIdentifiers = (0..9) - identifiersOfObjectsAfterRemoves

println "Identifiers of removed objects: " + removedObjectsIdentifiers
```

Comment: Thanks,I am very appreciate your answer,but I am using spock to test java code,and this list will be passed into java object,and I can't changed java code.is it impossible due to nobody provide a direct answer?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Maybe this time it will be more helpful :)

Comment: I am not sure whether any property can be add to Mock object.(I will check it).So it is impossible to combine index to item name.if it is possible,the thing will be far more easy than this.

Comment: It's possible thanks to MetaClass property (linked in my answer). Check it and we'll see if it's good method to deal with your problem.

Comment: Thanks,your answer still can't solve my problem(I added an image to tell why),but it is good enough for my question.