# How to change the variable name by reflection?

Tags: reflection, groovy

I have a variable like this:

```
   People model=Mock()//created by spock' mock
```

How to change the variable name "model" to "model_0" by reflection?

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: this is actually a special use case,and I have asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238107/how-to-compose-variable-name-dynamically,try to solve this problem by variable name composition,but it is dead way,so I want to try to do it by reflection.

Comment: This is a dead way too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any way to do that with reflection. I'm with @tim_yates in this one.

I'm no bytecode/compiler expert, but i do believe variable's names turn into symbols upon compilation, so they are not *changeable* at all. The following Java class:

```
public class Var {
  void a() {
    int myVar = 1;
    myVar += 1;
  }
}
```

Upon compilation and decompilation (using jd-gui), the code turns into:

```
public class Var
{
  void a()
  {
    int i = 1;
    i++;
  }
}
```

The variable name changed.

On Groovy, you can go for ASTs, which will give you full power over the generated tree. The following class:

```
class Asts {
  def wat() {
    Integer myVar = 90
  }
}
```

Will generate the following AST:

[image]

Now you can write your own [AST transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Local+AST+Transformations) to make the changes. Doesn't seem worth to me, though, a collection or map should suffice.